# How to implement Single Sign Out with WAAD in Java?

Tags: java, azure, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, ws-federation

I have implemented Single Sign On with Windows Azure Active Directory in a Java web app by following the [code sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java-samples/tree/master/WAAD.WebSSO.JAVA) and [this topic](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-java-web-single-sign-on/).
How can I implement Single Sign Out with WAAD in Java? I can’t find any useful topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sample, we can find out the Single Sign On URL is:

```
https://login.windows.net/common/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wctx=&id=passive&wct=${ISO_DATE_TIME_FORMAT_UTC}&wtrealm=${ENCODED_APP_ID_URI}&wreply=${ENCODED_REPLY_URL}
```

So the Single Sign Out URL is:

```
https://login.windows.net/common/wsfed?wa=wsignout1.0&wctx=&id=passive&wct=${ISO_DATE_TIME_FORMAT_UTC}&wtrealm=${ENCODED_APP_ID_URI}&wreply=${ENCODED_REPLY_URL}
```

The difference is the value of the parameter "wa".
Of course, we should replace "${...}" with proper values.